# Django, and React inside Docker inside a single Digital Ocean Droplet: 400 Bad Request for Django, React works fine

Tags: django, reactjs, docker, server

I have Django and React inside the same Docker container using `docker-compose.yml` and running this container inside a Digital Ocean Droplet running Ubuntu. When I navigate to http://my_ip_address:3000 which is the React app, it works just fine, but when I navigate to http://my_ip_address:8000 which is the Django app, I get a 400 Bad Request error from the server.

## project/back-end/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /nerdrich

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /nerdrich/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

COPY . /nerdrich/
EXPOSE 8000
```

## project/front-end/Dockerfile

```
# official node.js runtime for Docker
FROM node:12
# Create and set the directory for this container
WORKDIR /app/
# Install Application dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock /app/
RUN yarn install --no-optional
# Copy over the rest of the project
COPY . /app/

# Set the default port for the container
EXPOSE 3000

CMD yarn start
```

## project/docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: ./back-end
    command: python /nerdrich/manage.py runserver
    volumes:
      - ./back-end:/nerdrich
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  client:
    build: ./front-end
    volumes:
      - ./front-end:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - "web"
    command:
      yarn start
```

## project/back-end/nerdrich/.env

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['165.227.82.162']
```

I can provide any additional information if needed.

Comment: Can you update the post with logs from the `web` container?

Comment: After running ```docker logs the_web_container``` I get back ```System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 24, 2020 - 03:10:11
Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'nerdrich.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.```

Comment: making DEBUG=True in your settings works?

Comment: insert `print(ALLOWED_HOSTS)` in your `settings.py`, and see if django can get the correct host.

Comment: @Enix it printed out the correct IP address, changing DEBUG does not help.